# Google Cloud SQL Instance stuck at restarting

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

My Google Cloud SQL Instance is stuck at restarting. The operations panel shows that the restart is running. I also can't access the backups or do anything else with the instance, because it is busy with restarting.

Is there a way to get the server back up and running or access the backups so I can import the backups in a new sql instance?

Comment: I removed the "sql-server" tag. Did you resolve this problem? If so, what did you do? If not, what have you done?

Comment: Problem is resolved by Google Support. They had to manually force restart the instance.

Comment: @Laurens how did you talk with Google Support? Paid support level or any group or forum?

Comment: for me the restart gas been completed exactly after 1 hour. It may be because of the deadlock timeout that they have (600 seconds!) which cause the server to crash completely and then the restart can happen (https://stackoverflow.com/a/42201633/2088039)