# GCP SQL instance is stuck in update

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

My billing information changed and it triggered an update to a production GCP Cloud SQL instance. That instance has now been stuck on an update for several hours. None of the console buttons are working to restart or shut it down. My customers are now without service... does anyone know a way to force a restart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Outcome

Google Technical Support resolved the problem by force restarting the SQL instance 3 days earlier than I expected. Also, my project received a 1 month free trial period.

I saw that the only solution to this problem was to wait for Technical Support from one of the comments in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40808050/google-cloud-sql-instance-stuck-at-restarting). I sent an email to GCP billing support explaining that after reverting my billing information the SQL instance was still stuck.

They converted my ticket from billing support to technical support almost immediately by changing my account over to the trail version. The priority of the ticket was then escalated high enough that technical support could restart the instance manually.

Answer (score 0):

i have faced similar issue

my services connection goes up to around 3K and cloud instance was running on 100% CPU.

when new microservice deployed to Kubernetes cluster it won't started which leads to failure.

i have planned to restart Cloud instance and put export database dump to GCP cloud storage which also goes into the infinite state. Also older backup was not visible in GCP console.

instance status stuck at "instance being updated" and all old micro service working well and having connection with MYSQL during this period also.

when pressing restart button it's also not working to restart cloud SQL and command line `gcloud` giving error of `400`.

i have contacted Gcloud support also since my project is not under any organization they just ask for data and verifying it around 2 hours at last they forwarded the request to senior support engineer also spend some time for verification and at last suggested upgrading the account and purchase support plans.

**Resolution for me** :

Scale down all service to zero and which create some room for Cloud SQL instance. "**instance being updated**" value changed to "**under maintenance**" and instance started automatically.

For me the restart button was also not working to restart SQL instance and gcloud not working.